# What 'guna' mean in 'Guna atheetha'?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, gunas, lalita-sahasranama

The following [is a name](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Lalitha_Sahasranamam) in Lalitha sahastranaama

> **Guna atheetha** She who is beyond properties

I want to know what exactly **Guna** means in this name. Does it stands for **property** or related to three Gunas: Satva, Rajas, and Thamas.

The latter found to be more apt for me based on the following verse in Geetha

> When wise persons see that in all work there is no agent of action
> other than the three guṇas, and they **know Me to be transcendental to
> these guṇas**, they attain My divine nature.
>
> [[19, Chapter 14 : Guṇa Traya Vibhāg Yog, Bhagavad Gita]](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/14/verse/19)

Am I correct? I am asking this question because the name seems to be apt for other interpretations (guna as property) also.

Based on the context in which the name appears, what can be the exact interpretation for the name?

Comment: there is also a name 'nirakar' there so this may refer to the satva/raja... definition

Answer (score 2):

The word guna appears twice in the Sri Lalita Sahasranama. Swami Tapasyananda interprets the word guna as virtue in one case and Sattva, Rajas and Tamas in the other case.

> Om guna - nidhaye namah

**Sri Lalita Sahasranama 604**

> Salutations to Her who is a treasure house of virtues.

**Commentary by Swami Tapasyananda**

> Om gun'atitayai namah

**Sri Lalita Sahasranama 961**

> Salutations to Her who transcends the three Gunas of Prakrti known as
> Sattva, Rajas and Tamas.

**Commentary by Swami Tapasyananda**